# Add DIV/0 exception handling. I did something wrong but can't pin point where

Tags: c++

This is a simple weight conversion program. The purpose is to divide EnglishWeight1 5 pounds 12 ounces by number.
I use the try-throw-catch method to handle division by 0.

Please help.

```
//Class Declaration
class EnglishWeight
{
    private:
        int pounds, ounces;
    public:
        EnglishWeight(void); //0-argument constructor
        EnglishWeight(int lbs, int oz);
        EnglishWeight ScalarDivision(const int &s, int *check) const; 
};
```

```
//Member Function Definition
EnglishWeight::EnglishWeight(void)
{
    pounds = ounces = 0;
}
EnglishWeight::EnglishWeight(int lbs, int oz)
{
    pounds = lbs;
    ounces = oz;
}

EnglishWeight EnglishWeight::ScalarDivision(const int &s, int *check) const //Scalar Division function
{
    EnglishWeight sdivide; //Declare variable 
    try
    {
        if (s == 0) //DIV/0 check
            throw 0;
        else
        {
            sdivide.ounces = (pounds * 16) + ounces;
            sdivide.pounds = sdivide.ounces / (16 * s);
            sdivide.ounces = sdivide.ounces % 16;
            return sdivide;
        }
    }
    catch (int x)
    {
        *check = x;
    }
}

void EnglishWeight::Show() const
{
    std::cout << pounds << " pounds, " << ounces << " ounces";
}
```

```
//Main Driver
int main(void)
{
    EnglishWeight EnglishWeight1(5, 12);
    EnglishWeight sdiv1;
    int number = 0;
    int flag = 1;

        sdiv1 = EnglishWeight1.ScalarDivision(number, &flag);
    if (flag == 0)
        std::cout << "EnglishWeight1 / number = DIV/0" << std::endl;
    else
    {
        std::cout << "EnglishWeight1 / number = ";
        sdiv1.Show();
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Error: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000 which probably means the compiler is reading garbage value somewhere. I just don't know how to fix it.

Comment: There is no `return` specified in the case where the div-0 exception happens. Therefore you're basically lying to the caller of `EnglishWeight1.ScalarDivision` in claiming you'll return a `EnglishWeight` on all code paths. Frankly, I cannot fathom how your compiler did *not* emit some sort of warning about "not all code paths provide return value" or some similar phrasing.

Comment: Thanks, what's the best way to handle this since I can't return a NULL value?

Comment: Just return `sdivide` as-is. Your caller isn't going to use it regardless.

Comment: I just did that and still have the same problem. The errors are: `Exception thrown at 0x00007FFF99099129 in C++ Class.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: int at memory location 0x00000099D56FF204.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FF75D2876CD in C++ Class.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000.`

Comment: The error is thrown at `sdiv1 = EnglishWeight1.ScalarDivision(number, &flag);`

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cd8e82c8becdf56d

Comment: Actually I'm an idiot. Placed the `return sdivide` in the wrong place. Your suggestion works. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

@WhozCraig suggestion works. Thanks!

"There is no return specified in the case where the div-0 exception happens. Therefore you're basically lying to the caller of EnglishWeight1.ScalarDivision in claiming you'll return a EnglishWeight on all code paths. Frankly, I cannot fathom how your compiler did not emit some sort of warning about "not all code paths provide return value" or some similar phrasing."

"Just return sdivide as-is. Your caller isn't going to use it regardless"